# Convert string to multi dimensional array

Tags: c#, .net, xml, arrays

I am parsing an XML file and have hard coded a method to tear apart a string to create a multidimensional array. Here's a fragment of the XML I am parsing:

```
<MeasPropList Path="userList" Type="System.Double[]">
    {1960, 1980, 0}, {1980, 0, 0}, {1960, 1980, 1990}
</MeasPropList>
```

The <MeasPropList> element is used for any kind of data, not just arrays or numeric.
The equivalent result of this XML in C# is:

```
double[,] userList = new[,] { { 1960.0, 1980.0, 0.0 }, 
                       { 1980.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, 
                       { 1960.0, 1980.0, 1990.0 } };
```

I'll spare you the code I am using, it works ok but I am looking for a more elegant solution.
Is there a way I can use Array.ConvertAll<> ?
Is there an XML library function I can use to parse the XML numeric data?

[EDIT]
I posted the code I am using here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/15922/parsing-xml-to-create-ilist

Comment: You should start by including the code you're currently using.  We can't know if it's better without knowing where you're at now.  Oh, and if it works you should probably post on codereview.stackexchange instead.

Comment: right now I cannot think of a existing frameworkfunction for this - but it should be rather simple to write a basic generic parsing function (String.Split and Convert) to handle this kind of situation.

Comment: Basic split?  Problem there is , in and between {}.  Michael post some code.

Comment: I think the idea of an XML file is to layout information then just parse by elements?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

If you're not fixed on that format, you could use jagged arrays and an XmlSerializer:

```
    double[][][] d = new double[][][] { new double[][] {
                                            new double[] {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
                                            new double[] {4.0, 5.0, 6.0},
                                            new double[] {7.0, 8.0, 9.0}
                                        },
                                        new double[][] {
                                            new double[] {10.0, 11.0, 12.0},
                                            new double[] {13.0, 14.0, 15.0},
                                            new double[] {16.0, 17.0, 18.0}
                                        },
                                        new double[][] {
                                            new double[] {19.0, 20.0, 21.0},
                                            new double[] {22.0, 23.0, 24.0},
                                            new double[] {25.0, 26.0 ,27.0}
                                        }
                                    };

    XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(double[][][]));

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        x.Serialize(sw, d);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
    }
```

That yields the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfArrayOfArrayOfDouble xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ArrayOfArrayOfDouble>
    <ArrayOfDouble>
      <double>1</double>
      <double>2</double>
      <double>3</double>
    </ArrayOfDouble>
    <ArrayOfDouble>
      <double>4</double>
      <double>5</double>
      <double>6</double>
    </ArrayOfDouble>
    <ArrayOfDouble>
      <double>7</double>
      <double>8</double>
      <double>9</double>
    </ArrayOfDouble>
  </ArrayOfArrayOfDouble>
  <ArrayOfArrayOfDouble>
    <ArrayOfDouble>
      <double>10</double>
      <double>11</double>
      <double>12</double>
    </ArrayOfDouble>
    <ArrayOfDouble>
      <double>13</double>
      <double>14</double>
      <double>15</double>
    </ArrayOfDouble>
    <ArrayOfDouble>
      <double>16</double>
      <double>17</double>
      <double>18</double>
    </ArrayOfDouble>
  </ArrayOfArrayOfDouble>
  <ArrayOfArrayOfDouble>
    <ArrayOfDouble>
      <double>19</double>
      <double>20</double>
      <double>21</double>
    </ArrayOfDouble>
    <ArrayOfDouble>
      <double>22</double>
      <double>23</double>
      <double>24</double>
    </ArrayOfDouble>
    <ArrayOfDouble>
      <double>25</double>
      <double>26</double>
      <double>27</double>
    </ArrayOfDouble>
  </ArrayOfArrayOfDouble>
</ArrayOfArrayOfArrayOfDouble>
```

Comment: He wants to parse XML not create it.

Comment: @Blam I'm aware of that, but you can also deserialize this just by calling Deserialize, which is why I suggested that a different format might be an option.

Comment: OK but what about the  <MeasPropList Path="userList" Type="System.Double[]">

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parser = new MeasPropListParser<double>();
        var values = parser.GetValues("{1960, 1980, 0}, {1980, 0, 0}, {1960, 1980, 1990}");
    }


   public class MeasPropListParser<T>
    {
        private char[] comma = new char[] { ',' };
        private char[] rightBrace = new char[] { '}' };

        public T[,] GetValues(string input)        
        {
            var dims = GetDimensions(input);
            int rowCount = dims.Item1;
            int colCount = dims.Item2;

            T[,] array = new T[rowCount, colCount];
            var converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            var rows = GetRows(input);

            for (int x = 0; x < rowCount; x++)
            {
                var cols = new List<string>(rows[x].Split(comma, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
                for (int y = 0; y < colCount; y++)
                {
                    array[x, y] = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(cols[y]);
                }

            }

            return array;
        }

        private Tuple<int, int> GetDimensions(string input)
        {
            int rowCount = 0;
            int colCount = 0;
            foreach (var array in input.Trim().Split(rightBrace, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                rowCount++;
                if (colCount == 0)
                {
                    colCount = array.Split(comma, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
                }
            }
            return new Tuple<int, int>(rowCount, colCount);
        }

        private List<string> GetRows(string input)
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            foreach (var array in input.Trim().Split(rightBrace, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                list.Add(array.Replace("{", "").Trim());
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```